# how to download docx file created with the open xml sdk?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, openxml-sdk

Document.cs:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace GeneratedCode
{
    public class GeneratedClass
    {
        // Creates an Document instance and adds its children.
        public Document GenerateDocument()
        {
            Document document1 = new Document(){ MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes(){ Ignorable = "w14 w15 wp14" }  };
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Body body1 = new Body();

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "00100E91", RsidParagraphAddition = "009D5F75", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00100E91" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();

            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
            Languages languages1 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

            paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(languages1);

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

            Run run1 = new Run();

            RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
            Languages languages2 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

            runProperties1.Append(languages2);
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Hello";

            run1.Append(runProperties1);
            run1.Append(text1);
            BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart(){ Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };
            BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd(){ Id = "0" };

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);
            paragraph1.Append(bookmarkStart1);
            paragraph1.Append(bookmarkEnd1);

            SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties(){ RsidRPr = "00100E91", RsidR = "009D5F75" };
            PageSize pageSize1 = new PageSize(){ Width = (UInt32Value)11906U, Height = (UInt32Value)16838U };
            PageMargin pageMargin1 = new PageMargin(){ Top = 1134, Right = (UInt32Value)850U, Bottom = 1134, Left = (UInt32Value)1701U, Header = (UInt32Value)708U, Footer = (UInt32Value)708U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
            Columns columns1 = new Columns(){ Space = "708" };
            DocGrid docGrid1 = new DocGrid(){ LinePitch = 360 };

            sectionProperties1.Append(pageSize1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(pageMargin1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(columns1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(docGrid1);

            body1.Append(paragraph1);
            body1.Append(sectionProperties1);

            document1.Append(body1);
            return document1;
        }


    }
}
```

I want to get the document created on this code (code from Open XML SDK).

how by pressing the button to get ready document (get hello.docx)?

Created project: asp.net mvc 4
add: 
1) Controller
2) View-> code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Get docx file" />
    }
```

**Thank you all.**

The problem is solved.

Method:

```
    public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] document = new GeneratedClass().CreateDocumenBytes();
            return File(document, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "Contract.docx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Экспорт договора в Word","GetFile","get")
    }
```

Comment: this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+download+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to create an action that returns a `FileResult` or a `ContentResult`. I.e. your action should make a call to

```
return File(...);
```

or

```
return Content(...);
```

You must specify parameters for the file name, file content, encoding... Look at the documentation of:

```
[FileResult][1]
[ContentResult][2]
```

And the documentation of the `Content` and `File` methods of the [Controller class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_methods(v=vs.118).aspx) (mentioned above).

If you want to do it using a submit button, your action must be decorated with `[HttpPost]`. You can also expose it as a link, and implement a GET action. In any case, you should send extra information so that the servers know whic document is being requested (form values, if you use POST, or Url parameters, if you use GET).